# Converting non responsive three column lay-out to bootstrap three column lay-out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i have an website using a three column lay-out with a fixed width of 1000px. I want to convert this to an bootstrap responsive lay-out. What i did was the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2">Main</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-8">Left</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've set the container width for @media (min-width: 1200px) to width : 1000px. The problem i have now is that my sidebars are to small and the middle column is too wide. Changing the left and right col to col-lg-3 makes the colum to wide and the center column to small. I know bootstrap works with percentage so my question is, is this just how bootstrap works and i have to deal with it? Or is it somehow possible to set an fixed width to the sidebars? or is there an other way to make this happen?

thanks

Comment: `set an fixed width to the sidebars` of course you can set fixed width. just don't use col- class.

Comment: Though anything less than 1 Bootstrap column is pretty small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Bootstrap works. If you want to adapt it to your own liking, you should give your Main, Left and Right divs a class of their own and just adapt the % in your CSS.

Just be aware that creating your own %-width DOES NOT make it responsive! What I mean to say is that your divs will resize according to the browser-width, resulting in a very skinny website on mobile phones. Best is to combine this solution with Bootstrap, so Bootstrap takes over whenever your browser gets under X pixels wide, or to write your own @media and change the look of your website according to the width of the page.

Edit: Of course you could also try and override the bootstrap width in your own CSS, but this might result in some weird things when you use the same col-width again on another page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive tried setting my own percentages and you are right about the page getting super skinny on mobile phone. Setting my own col width will result in the "left" of the main column not being set properly and thus overlapping the left column.
I guess im stuck at using the way it works with bootstrap but that will result in some heavy redesigning of a lot of websites...